# Paypal error #520009 - important information missing on file with parallel payment mode

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am try to implement paypal parallel Payment, I am facing this issue on sandbox accounts.

I am getting following error as response:

Request is :

```
{
    'returnUrl': 'http: //127.0.0.1: 8000/accounts/pay/return/30/1a9dc4f47a0947ecb0783dcd3f8e0b4e/',
    'displayMaxTotalAmount': True,
    'maxNumberOfPayments': 1,
    'maxTotalAmountOfAllPayments': 5245.4,
    'maxNumberOfPaymentsPerPeriod': 1,
    'endingDate': '2014-11-15T14: 59: 55.630347+00: 00',
    'preapprovalKey': u'PA-2W012595BX194751T',
    'actionType': 'PAY',
    'ipnNotificationUrl': 'http: //127.0.0.1: 8000/accounts/ipn/30/1a9dc4f47a0947ecb0783dcd3f8e0b4e/',
    'cancelUrl': 'http: //127.0.0.1: 8000/accounts/pay/cancel/30/1a9dc4f47a0947ecb0783dcd3f8e0b4e/',
    'startingDate': '2014-08-17T14: 59: 55.630923+00: 00',
    'pinType': 'NOT_REQUIRED',
    'receiverList': {
        'receiver': [
            {
                'amount': '1689.19',
                'email': 'xxxx-facilitator@gmail.com',
                'primary': False
            },
            {
                'amount': '662.23',
                'email': u'xx_buz@gmail.com',
                'primary': False
            },
            {
                'amount': '1491.60',
                'email': u'xxx4@email.com',
                'primary': False
            },
            {
                'amount': '1005.88',
                'email': u'yyy@gmail.com',
                'primary': False
            },
            {
                'amount': '396.50',
                'email': u'g3@gmail.com',
                'primary': False
            }
        ]
    },
    'requestEnvelope': {
        'errorLanguage': 'en_US'
    },
    'currencyCode': u'USD'
}
```

Response is :

```
{
    "responseEnvelope": {
        "timestamp": "2014-08-17T08:06:54.900-07:00",
        "ack": "Failure",
        "correlationId": "e8dcbcccb34ac",
        "build": "11853342"
    },
    "error": [
        {
            "errorId": "520009",
            "domain": "PLATFORM",
            "subdomain": "Application",
            "severity": "Error",
            "category": "Application",
            "message": "The transaction cannot be completed as the sender has some important information missing on file."
        }
    ]
}
```

I am not sure why this error is coming, I feel its related to amount which I am using for distribution that is 5245.4, if I use amount less then 5000.0 that is 2000 or something then everything works fine. The above request works fine if distribute amount up to 2000.0 USD, This all is running on sandbox accounts.

Can any body please help to understand this issue.

Thanks in advance

Ansh J

Answer (score 0):

Is the PayPal account you're sending from a business account?  It sounds like you're running into personal account limitations.  Either that or that you need to verify a bank account and confirm a credit card on your account.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I am using business account and having sufficient amount in it, I am using sandbox accounts so I thing credit card and bank account validation is not the issue.